# Navigating XML using XPATH with a different namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am struggling to find out how to navigate in to the area of the xml that uses namespaces. Using basic xpath i can navigate to the message detail node fine, but I am not sure what I need to do in terms of getting in to that block as everything inside uses namespaces. Please could someone help?

Thanks

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Message>
        <MessageList>
            <MessageCount>2</MessageCount>
            <DateTimeStamp>2016-02-11T12:50:26</DateTimeStamp>
            <MessageDetail>
                <MessageID>2332445456767</MessageID>
                <Env:MessageContainer xmlns:Env="http://www.somesite.com/schema/v1.0/envelope" xmlns:BS="http://www.somesite.com/schema/v1.0/BusinessServices">
                    <Env:MessageParties>
```

> ```
> public List<String> getRefs(String xmlMessageToSend)
> {
>     try
>     {
>         Document doc = createDocument(xmlMessageToSend.getBytes());
>         XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
>         xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
>
>             @Override
>             public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix)
>             {
>                 if (prefix == null)
>                     throw new NullPointerException("Null prefix");
>                 else if ("Env".equals(prefix))
>                     return "http://www.om.com/schema/v1.0/envelope";
>                 else if ("BS".equals(prefix))
>                     return "http://www.o.com/schema/v1.0/BusinessServices";
>
>                 return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI)
>             {
>                 throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI)
>             {
>                 throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
>             }
>
>         });
>         XPathExpression exp = xpath
>                 .compile("/Message/MessageList/MessageDetail/Env:MessageContainer");
>         Node result = (Node)exp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
>         System.out.println(result.getTextContent());
>     }
>     catch (XPathExpressionException | SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException e)
>     {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
>     return new ArrayList<String>();
> }
> ```

Comment: Use the namespace prefix with the nodeName. Eg:: /Env:MessageContainer

Comment: You could also use general pathing. //Messagedetail/*[2]/*[1] ...

Comment: @Jagrut that didnt work

Comment: @Helmer - this did work, how would that change if there were multiple message detail nodes though?

Comment: Right now, this question cannot be answered. Tell us what programming language and library you are using XPath with - and show this code.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - updated

Comment: Thanks. As the next step, show a complete, but minimal example of your XML input and show what exactly you expect as the output. Help on this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you're using to navigate the document, but generally, there should be a way in the API of whatever you're using for you to declare a namespace prefix that matches the one on Env:MessageContainer. Then you can use that prefix in your XPath, e.g. `//e:MessageContainer` (assuming you mapped 'e' to `"http://www.somesite.com/schema/v1.0/envelope"`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a message prefix in the XPath expression. For example,

```
//foo:MessageContainer
```

This prefix need not be the same prefix used for the namespace URI as in the original document. Here I've used the prefix `foo` even though it was `Env` in your document. As long as both prefixes map to the same URI (http://www.somesite.com/schema/v1.0/envelope in this example) the XPath will match.

How exactly you bind this prefix to the desired namespace URI varies depending on the host language in which the XPath expression is embedded. In XSLT, for example, you simply declare the relevant prefixes in the XSLT stylesheet, much as you would in any other XML document. In XOM, by contrast, you have to supply an [`XPathContext`](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/XPathContext.html) object that maps the namespace prefixes accordingly. And so on for other languages and APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your elements via e.g.

```
//Env:MessageContainer
```

But to achieve this, your `xmlns:Env="http://www.somesite.com/schema/v1.0/envelope" xmlns:BS="http://www.somesite.com/schema/v1.0/BusinessServices"` should be defined in the `<root>` element instead of (or in addition to) the `<Env:MessageContainer>` element.

But if you cannot change your source XML, the correct solution would be the comprehensive style of writing the same thing as above:

```
//*[local-name()='MessageContainer'][namespace-uri()='http://www.somesite.com/schema/v1.0/envelope']
```